# could kafka-connect distributed worker work with topic 'connect-offset' with configuration 'cleanup.policy=compact,delete'

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ibm-eventstreams

I started a kafka-connect distributed worker cluster which uses the topic `connect-offset` for offset storage:

```
offset.storage.topic=connect-offset
```

Since the broker is provided with default policy 'cleanup.policy=delete', when creating a topic with 'cleanup.policy=compact', I will get 'cleanup.policy=compact,delete' for this topic eventually. Which cause kafka-connect worker process to throw exception:

> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Topic 'slpe-connect-offset' supplied via the 'offset.storage.topic' property is required to have 'cleanup.policy=compact' to guarantee consistency and durability of source connector offsets, but found the topic currently has 'cleanup.policy=compact,delete'. Continuing would likely result in eventually losing source connector offsets and problems restarting this Connect cluster in the future. Change the 'offset.storage.topic' property in the Connect worker configurations to use a topic with 'cleanup.policy=compact'.

Question: is there any kafka-connect worker config allow eating this exception to keep worker process? although it's a risk but `delete` won't happen until it hits either retention or size limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This validation was introduced in [KAFKA-9216](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9216) ([PR](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/8828)) and affects 2.3.2, 2.6.0, 2.4.2, 2.5.1 versions:

> The current change helps guard against users running Connect with topics that have delete cleanup policy enabled, which will remove all connector configurations, source offsets, and connector & task statuses that are older than the retention time. This means that, for example, the configuation for a long-running connector could be deleted by the broker, and this will cause restart issues upon a subsequent rebalance or restarting of Connect worker(s).
> Connect behavior requires that its internal topics are compacted and not deleted after some retention time

Therefore, it highly unrecommeded to use delete clean policy for Kafka Connect interanl topics: just recreate those topics.

There is no any config property to ignore this validation, but if you want, you can downgrade Kafka Connect to a version without it.

Comment: Can you elaborate "just recreate those topics"?